# Como cargar un select con un option definido de la base de datos

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con visual studio 2015 mvc 5 c# en el cual tengo una lista de artículos que vienen con una configuración predeterminada pero también se puede crear desde cero o se puede modificar las ya predeterminadas.

Tengo en mi base de datos una tabla llamada `Doors` la cual tiene un solo registro de una sola puerta ya configurada que es con la que estoy probando. Entonces en una vista me carga unos combobox con las opciones de personalización de la puerta. Las tablas ya poseen datos y me carga en los combobox al ingresar a la configuración.

Ahora lo que quisiera es que al yo seleccionar una puerta e ir a la vista de configuración los combos ya tengan seleccionados los datos de esa puerta.

En mi vista index tengo este script pero no me funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var datos = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.datos)');
            $("#cbMaterial").val(datos.Material.Id);
});
```

En el var `datos` cuando lo inspecciono en el navegador el `ViewBag.datos` tiene cargados los datos de la puerta que seleccione en su totalidad pero al querer asignárselo al combobox `cbMaterial` no funciona.

Mis combos ya cargan de esta manera en un archivo js

```
function GetAllMaterial() {
$.ajax({
    url: urlGetAllMaterial,
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var option = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                option += '<option value="' + data[i].Id + '">' + data[i].Description + '</option>';


            }
            $("#cbMaterial").empty().append(option);

        }
        else {
            MensajeModal("Error al obtener Material", 5);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        MensajeModal(msgErrorinterno, 5);
    }
});
```

}

Y en el controldor tengo el ActionResult `GetAllMaterial` con lo que hace todo el proceso de llenar los combos.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAllMaterial()
    {
        try
        {
            BusinessLogic.lnMaterial _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnMaterial();
            return Json(_LN.GetAllMaterial());
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Cuando yo seleciono el objeto a modificar el controlador recibe esos datos en el controlador

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
    {
        ViewBag.ConfiDoor = "active";
        BusinessLogic.lnDoors _LN = new BusinessLogic.lnDoors();
        if (Id > 0 )
        {
            var Door = _LN.GetDoorsById(Id.Value);
            var serializar = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewBag.Door = serializar.Serialize(Door);
        }           
        return View();
    }
```

Ya ahí colocando un punto de interrupción confirme que el controlador recibe los datos del item a modificar y igual el `ViewBag.datos` del index con un `console.log()` vi que tenia los datos del item lo que sigue sin hacer es ya seleccionar la option del combobox que ya pertenece a ese item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si vas a usar `json` no se usa ningun `@Html.Raw()` deberias realizar una llamada ajax usando `jquery` con el `$.ajax` invocando el action que retorna el json

[Populate (Bind) DropDownList using jQuery AJAX and JSON in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

la idea es que desde el cliente uses algo como esto

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        $.each(response, function () {
            ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

para obtener los items del combo

Ahora bien, para asignar la seleccion seria la misma idea, crear una llamada ajax al action en el controller y que retorne lo que ahora recibes en el `ViewBag.datos` para poder asignar el option que debe seleccionar

Comment: Es casi lo mismo a como lo tengo en mi codigo, acabo de editar la pregunta y agregue mas detalles. Pero sigue sin agarrar el dato determinado del Door

Comment: Pero lo que llega en ViewBag.datos, no puede llegar de esa forma, tiene que llegar por otra llamada ajax que realices al action, esto debera realizarse despues que se ejeutaron las anteriores llamadas, recuerda que $.ajax es asincrono, por lo que invocara el action y continua ejecutando

Comment: en el success de la llamada ajax a urlGetAllMaterial, es que debes invocar ese action (tambien por ajax) y asignar el valor que debe seleccionar

Comment: Guiándome de otros post  y tu respuesta pude solucionarlo Gracias (y)